# PySpark get minute only?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In snowflake, you can do something like:

```
SELECT
my_event_time,
DATE_TRUNC('minute',my_event_time)::TIME AS minute
FROM table
```

And it would return something like:

```
my_event_time             | minute
-------------------------------------
2020-08-17 13:23:49.227.  | 13:23:00
```

Removing everything except the actual minute, can this be done in Pyspark df? The `date_trunc('minute', ...)` in Pyspark does something else, it doesnt remove the date part.

Comment: I think you want to _parse_ or _format_ the date. Truncating removes everything to the left

Comment: @OneCricketeer date trunc doesnt remove the left part in pyspark

Comment: What is your spark version?

Answer (score 1):

Use [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format) function and pass required time format.

```
spark.sql("select date_format(current_timestamp,'HH:mm:ss') time").show()

+--------+
|    time|
+--------+
|10:48:13|
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spark.sql("current_timestamp,minute(current_timestamp)").show()
```